# I asked a question that is a month old, is it okay to delete?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I asked a question about Windows 10 and its start menu [here](https://superuser.com/q/1486012/1087482). It's one month old, has no answers, and only one comment I forgot to respond to. Should I delete it and ask it again, or should I respond to this comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleted posts count against a post ban.

This is **not** a good idea. Better to respond, and maybe update with what versions you have this issue with.

Comment: even if it has no answers?

Comment: @nickylego10 - All contributions that are submitted count towards or against your ability to submit new questions and answers.